# Help me simplify this dirty code

Tags: bash

Ok I have lines of these logs and I wish to pick out instances the same.

```
1: 50.678 MH/s (8271) 2: 50.675 MH/s (8109) 3: 50.672 MH/s (8087) 4: 50.687 MH/s (8147) 5: 50.664 MH/s (8073) 6: 50.677 MH/s (8144) 7: 50.684 MH/s (8088) 8: 44.676 MH/s (8323/1) 9: 50.675 MH/s (7918) 10: 0.000 MH/s
1: 50.678 MH/s (8271) 2: 50.675 MH/s (8109) 3: 50.672 MH/s (8087) 4: 50.687 MH/s (8147) 5: 50.664 MH/s (8073) 6: 50.677 MH/s (8144) 7: 50.684 MH/s (8088) 8: 0.000 MH/s (8323/1) 9: 50.675 MH/s (7918) 10: 0.000 MH/s
```

Using my dirty code I get an output

```
10 1
8 1
```

I am looking for instances of 0.000 and counting back to the corresponding number and adding a 1 to each time this appears in logs.

```
grep -E -o ".{0,4}0.000" varlog.txt | 
awk -F':' '{print $1}' > file.txt && 
sed '/.\{3\}/d' <file.txt >file1.txt && 
sort file1.txt | 
uniq -c | 
sort -r > file2.txt && 
awk ' { t = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = t; print; } ' file2.txt >> output.txt
```

The code above is what I am using, could someone tidy this up, it's an embarrassment I know.

Comment: Are you saying your code works and you literally want a cleanup, or are you saying it does not work? You have many separate operations in your solution... if that is a solution. I think it is not clear what you are asking and this is why you are downvoted.

Comment: It would be helpful if describe in text what the code is supposed to do, and add more lines of sample input

Comment: Are you sure that's only two lines of data? It looks like it was once several lines that you didn't format

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: Thank very much for your comments most appreciated, apologies for not adding more description and detail, for sure will make sure i add this next time i need help. Thankyou also waltinator for supplying the spellcheck syntax checker.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if your data is organized into lines of whitespace-delimited fields, where each collection of four fields constitutes some sort of group.

So, for example, for your data, you have the following groups (here one group per line):

```
$ awk '{ for (i = 1; i<= NF; i += 4) print $i, $(i+1), $(i+2), $(i+3); }' varlog.txt
1: 50.678 MH/s (8271)
2: 50.675 MH/s (8109)
3: 50.672 MH/s (8087)
4: 50.687 MH/s (8147)
5: 50.664 MH/s (8073)
6: 50.677 MH/s (8144)
7: 50.684 MH/s (8088)
8: 44.676 MH/s (8323/1)
9: 50.675 MH/s (7918)
10: 0.000 MH/s
1: 50.678 MH/s (8271)
2: 50.675 MH/s (8109)
3: 50.672 MH/s (8087)
4: 50.687 MH/s (8147)
5: 50.664 MH/s (8073)
6: 50.677 MH/s (8144)
7: 50.684 MH/s (8088)
8: 0.000 MH/s (8323/1)
9: 50.675 MH/s (7918)
10: 0.000 MH/s
```

If I understand you correctly, you want to count how many times each "label" (number at the start of one of the line above) corresponds to a value of zero (or `0.000` to be precise).

Let's count them by using the "label" as a key in an associative array, `count`, and increment the count each time the value is exactly the string `0.000`.  Then, let's output those counts when we have read all the data.

```
$ awk '{ for (i = 1; i<= NF; i += 4) if ($(i+1) == "0.000") ++count[$i] } END { for (label in count) print label, count[label] }' varlog.txt
10: 2
8: 1
```

We're getting the colons "for free" here as they are part of the data.

I'm not entirely sure how you want this sorted at the end, but if you want to sort it decreasing numerically on the second column, and write it to `output.txt`, pipe the result through

```bsh
sort -k 2,2rn -o output.txt
```

Comment: OK you sir are a genius, I just pasted in the above code and you've even pre-empted my next question of sorting order also. I can't actually thank you enough. Thank you so much.

Comment: May i also add i can't even slightly begin to work out how you resolved that so quick, i guess you must just literally think in this language, much respect.

Comment: @KenDoe Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).